# Creating a Database Class -- Where to Store Credentials?

Tags: php, oop

Working on a mobile app that needs to use a public API for accessing a database (but this won't affect the question).

Anyway, I am using PHP with MySQL and the Android/iPhone app will make POST requests to the PHP files.  I am creating the connection to the database and wanted to create a class to do it.  However, I am unsure where to put actual login credentials for the database.

I saw mention of outside the webroot so it's more secure.  Should I then create a database class inside /lib that handles the connection and includes the config.inc.php file?  Or do you guys recommend something totally different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're proposing looks totally fine to me. A config file outside of the web root with a properly configured web server is, generally speaking, totally fine from a security point of view.

Comment: Great, so then I just include the config file within my Database class file?